# Thunking - Windows 7

Tags: c#, interop, 16-bit

I am trying to write a very simple thunk that can be used from 16bit FoxPro to ultimately call a 64bit shiny WCF client.

I know I can't pass complex data types between them so I just want to pass a file name that data will be written to.

Problem is I can't even get the thunk to work. I am starting with

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29727/Generic-Thunk-of-Windows

but the call to

```
ghKernelDll = LoadLibrary("kernel.dll");
```

returns null. if i put kernel32 in there is it ok but that is to be expected - right? is it because I am running this application on my shiny 64 desktop? What do I need to be able to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it might have something to do with the fact that [16-bit code doesn't run on 64-bit versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423). In fact, to the best of my knowledge, `kernel.dll` doesn't even exist in 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Hi- you are indeed correct. I had to use my Windows XP virtual machine in the end....

Comment: Thanks - wanted to wait to see if I could extract more info, but your right. I'll do it now. Thank you Adam